# Blazor WebAssembly: builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication throws Exception => Cannot read property 'join' of undefined

Tags: blazor, webassembly, azure-ad-msal

My first ever attempt at using MSAL Authorization and it fails for me in Blazor.  Any Clues (it's going to be a simple answer I think?)

Small repo available [here](https://github.com/Discovery-support/BlazorApp4_Msal_Exception)

Client File: Program.cs

```cs
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options => //THROWS EXCEPTION!!!!!
{
    options.ProviderOptions.AdditionalScopesToConsent.Add($"https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read");
});

var baseAddress = builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress;
builder.Services.AddHttpClient(baseAddress, client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress))
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

Unexpected Result: Exception thrown

crit:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
>         Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined
>         TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined
>             at Function.createUserManager (https://localhost:44391/_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js:1:6020)
>             at Function.initializeCore (https://localhost:44391/_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js:1:5035)
>             at Function.init (https://localhost:44391/_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js:1:4575)
>             at https://localhost:44391/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:9873
>             at new Promise ()
>             at Object.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (https://localhost:44391/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:9841)
>             at _mono_wasm_invoke_js_marshalled (https://localhost:44391/_framework/wasm/dotnet.3.2.0.js:1:171294)
>             at do_icall (wasm-function[6049]:0x10f8b1)
>             at do_icall_wrapper (wasm-function[1896]:0x50b6a)
>             at interp_exec_method (wasm-function[1120]:0x2588e)

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this...

```html
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    ...

    options.ProviderOptions.AdditionalScopesToConsent.Add(
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send");
    options.ProviderOptions.AdditionalScopesToConsent.Add(
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read");
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1#request-additional-access-tokens

Hope it helps!

**EDIT 1:**
My client `Program.cs`

`using System.Net.Http;`
`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;`

Add the below reference in `Index.html` page

```
<script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
```

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

            builder.Services.AddHttpClient("BlazorWasmAADMsal.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

            // Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
            builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("BlazorWasmAADMsal.ServerAPI"));

            builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("api://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/API.Access");
            });

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
```

**EDIT 2:**
Did some minor changes. The working project has been uploaded [here](https://github.com/abhimantiwari/BlazorApp4_Msal_Exception). Successful login screen shot added in answer for reference. :-)

[image]

**EDIT 3:**

Azure Active Directory (AAD) Microsoft Graph API scopes are required by an app to read user data and send mail. After adding the Microsoft Graph API permissions in the Azure AAD portal, the additional scopes are configured in the Client app.

Last time i missed to enabled below lines, I have enabled it in `Program.cs`

```js
  builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
       {
options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read");
     }
```

It was a bizarre error, never expected and had seen it.

The reference of AuthenticationService.js in Index.html was not correct. I have corrected it to be...

```
<script src="_content/Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
```

I have also uploaded the latest code [here](https://github.com/abhimantiwari/BlazorApp4_Msal_Exception-master)

The `IAccessTokenProvider.RequestToken` method provides an overload that allows an app to provision an access token with a given set of scopes.

In a Razor component, you can write something like below:

```js
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@inject IAccessTokenProvider TokenProvider

...

var tokenResult = await TokenProvider.RequestAccessToken(
    new AccessTokenRequestOptions
    {
        Scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send", 
            "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read" }
    });

if (tokenResult.TryGetToken(out var token))
{
    ...
}
```

`AccessTokenResult.TryGetToken` returns:

`true` with the token for use.
`false` if the token isn't retrieved.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: The exception is thrown by AddMsalAuthentication, it never reaches the call to AdditionalScopesToConsent method. In my project I hold the scopes in appsettings.json and iterate through them, but this iteration is never started because AddMsalAuthentication throws an exception even if there are no scopes to add.

Comment: Does it work if you remove MsalAuth code?
Hope you don't have this line duplicate in your `Program.cs` `builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");`

A simple minimal repro project will help in understanding the root cause.

Comment: Yes, works perfectly without the builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication line.  Only invoked builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app") the one time only.  Thank you for the help.  The project is quite large, but fails very early on in the program.cs start up file.

Comment: I think I am using the AddMsalAuthentication from the wrong library.  Any chance of a list of Nuget packages and using statements that provide the AddMsalAuthentication extension method?  I tried a brand new clean WebAssembly project and the method was not known, adding these packages and usings made it compile, but it still throws same exception.

Comment: Which type of Auth are you using? Please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/standalone-with-microsoft-accounts?view=aspnetcore-3.1). It has explained, how to configure, step by steps.

I'm using this- `"Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal" Version="3.2.0"` and it's working fine for me.

Comment: @Discovery-Support I have edited my answer to add my Main method code.

Comment: It's still failing for me - you can find a [repo here](https://github.com/Discovery-support/BlazorApp4_Msal_Exception)

Comment: I did some minor change and fixed the issue. The working project has been uploaded [here](https://github.com/abhimantiwari/BlazorApp4_Msal_Exception).

Successful login screen shot added in answer for reference. :-)

Comment: Yes it works because you removed the AddMsalAuthentication from Program.cs , this is where my understanding fails... I thought I *needed* AddMsalAuthentication (which throws an exception) to be able to access and request a Microsoft Graph bearer token for the User.Read (and Calendar.ReadWrite) claims?  Can you explain this?

Comment: @Discovery-Support I missed that somehow. I have fixed that and edited my answer. Also uploaded the latest code in new [repo](https://github.com/abhimantiwari/BlazorApp4_Msal_Exception-master/tree/master/BlazorApp4_Msal_Exception-FIXED). Hope it helps you, if it does, please mark it as answered.

Comment: I am still struggling  :(  - but I thank you for all your efforts.  The repo that you supplied no longer allows a user to *Register* with Identity Server.  This is proving to be far more complicated than I originally thought. Ideally I would like a user to register and login, the access for Microsoft Graph would be prompted for if the user (say) clicks a button.  I am more than eager to mark this as answered.

Comment: @Discovery-Support - I believe you are no more getting the error in questions "Exception => Cannot read property 'join' of undefined". Not sure why you are not able to register new user, probably you can debug and see the flow. To protect an API or Component with AAD, you can follow these [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-3.1). And for any new errors/ issues, I would suggest to log a new question for better tracking purpose. Rather you can give reference of this question there. Thanks!

Comment: My problem was solved by adding the correct path of JS library 
"<script src="_content/Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal/AuthenticationService.js"></script>"

Answer (score 4):

Check that the MSAL script is in your index page:

`<script src="_content/Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal/AuthenticationService.js"></script>`

This fixed the same issue for me, when I was retro-fitting MSAL into an existing Blazor WASM app that was referencing the JS file:

`<script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js"></script>`

If this JS ref exists, remove it and replace with the MSAL version.

Comment: Also, make sure the old index file is not cached in the browser.  It's an old one, but still catches me out.

Comment: For those who wonder how to avoid old index file, hold ctrl + click refresh on edge to refresh the page and the cache.

Comment: Great, just needed this to fix my issue.
I followed this article to setup auth with msal 

https://medium.com/@mariekie/add-authentication-to-an-existing-blazor-standalone-application-ab6aff8d0bf2

Comment: how come there is no elegant solution and we have to include JS files like peasants??